# root directory for pytest logging using pytest.ini

Tags: python, pytest, ini

I'm looking for a way to anchor the log file location that I gather during `pytest`.

I currently have a project

```
py_project
   |
   + src/
       + ...
   + tests/
       + logs/
           + pytest-logs.log
   + pytest.ini
   |
```

with a `pytest.ini` file at the root level with the (standard) line included:

```
log_file = logs/pytest-logs.log
```

The expectation is that this puts the test logs in a folder logs inside the tests folder when the running testing from the IDE which initiates from that folder.

However, If I'm just doing something from the CLI from the root location such as:

```
py_project % pytest .
```

`pytest` will create a new log folder at the project root level (not desired) and use that.

So, the baseline question is:  How can I put a project root dir reference in the `pytest.ini` folder or reference something `pytest` already knows to anchor this reference?  The [dox](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir) say that the `pytest.ini` folder establishes the root directory location, but I don't know how to get a handle to that reference.  (I'm not very experienced working with .ini files so this might be something trivial.)

I'd rather not use a full absolute path on current machine, as I'd like this to work on other machines.